# has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, angular2

На сервере:

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", b =>
                {
                    b.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                }
            );
        });
```

С сайта шлю запрос:

```
this._httpClient.get('API', { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(resut =>
  this.data = resut
);
```

Ловлю такое сообщение в консоле сайта:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:20019/api/' from origin
>   'https://localhost:44331' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value
>   of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not
>   be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>   The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
>   [https://localhost:44331/] output

а на веб апи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: либо .AllowCredentials() либо * судя по сообщению

Comment: Ну так-то .AllowCredentials() позволяет передавать учетные данные. Разве нет? А я как раз хочу передать вин аутентификацию.

Comment: значить не получится использовать Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * , впишите туда конкретный домен, которому разрешен доступ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хорошо, какие у меня варианты все пофиксить?

Comment: я полагаю что Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:44331

Comment: @StrangerintheQ -это в хеадер запроса от сайта нужно приложить?

Comment: ответа от сервера

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91116/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-iluxa1810).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщение

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:20019/api/' from origin
>   'https://localhost:44331' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value
>   of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not
>   be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>   The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
>   [https://localhost:44331/] output

гласит, что вы не можете использовать одновременно

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

и

```
.AllowCredentials();
```

когда делаете авторизованный запрос на 'http://localhost:20019/api' cо страницы, загруженной с адреса 'https://localhost:44331'

Для того, чтобы браузер смог выполнить данный запрос c **CORS** и **авторизацией** Вам необходимо добавить следующие заголовки к ответу сервера:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:44331
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```